# Evaluating $xe^{-x/\lambda}\big|_0^\infty$ with and without L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

How to evaluate
$$\left. \frac x{e^{\frac x\lambda}} \right|_0^\infty$$ using:

1. L'Hopital's Rule
2. Without using L'Hopital's Rule?

Or should I use the rule partially for $\infty$ and not use it for $0$?

Comment: What you need to recognize is that your expression is shorthand notation for $\Bigl(\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} {x\over e^{x/\lambda}}\Bigr)- \color{maroon}{0\over e^0}$. You can use L'Hôpital to compute the limit. The term $\color{maroon}{0\over e^0}$ is just a number (0). (So, the answer to your last question is "yes".)

Comment: I can't understand your question, may be I am ignorant of the operator you used here, could you please explain a little bit. Thanks

Comment: @DavidMitra So, I can't use L'Hopital's Rule to compute the limit at 0?

Comment: If this is connected to your past question then your function is wrong: $$e^{-\lambda x}=\frac1{e^{\lambda x}}\neq\frac1{e^{x/\lambda}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using L'Hosptal's rule at the point $\infty$, since both numerator and denominator tend to $\infty$, differentiating $x$ with respect to $x$ will give 1 and differentiating denominator ${e^{\frac x\lambda}}$ will give ${e^{\frac x\lambda}} \frac{1}{\lambda}$ which will give $\frac{\lambda}{e^{\frac x\lambda}}$, which goes to $0$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to evaluate is to find
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{e^{x/\lambda}}$$ Clearly, $\dfrac{x}{e^{x/\lambda}} > 0$.
Note that we have $e^{x/\lambda} > \dfrac{x^2/\lambda^2}{2!}$. Hence,
$$0 < \dfrac{x}{e^{x/\lambda}} < \dfrac{2 \lambda^2}{x}$$
Now letting $x \to \infty$, what do we get?